# Hard coding values referenced in another excel worksheet with excel interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am writing an application that copies one worksheet from several different workbooks into another workbook. The problem is, some of the values in the worksheets that I am copying are referenced from another worksheet in that workbook, so when I copy the worksheet over I am left with a bunch of `#REF!` errors. Is there an easy way to hard code those values into the worksheet before copying it to the new workbook using excel interop?

Comment: How are you copying a worksheet from one workbook to another? If you are copying the worksheet's range (A1:X99) You should be able to copy the values rather than formulas. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16038605/211627).

Comment: I'm not I'm using the `WorkSheet.copy()` function

Comment: In that case, you can use the suggestion in the post above to replace all formulas in the target worksheet with values, then copy it to a new workbook, then close the original workbook without saving changes.